# Pass event args and event object to event handler without arrow function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

So, I've been looking around for the correct way to pass both a parameter object and the event object to an event handler in react. Is there a best practise?

The only way I found is to use an arrow function and pass in both the event object and the parameter, like this.

```
<Button onClick={(e) => this.updateProgress(e, 1)} >Increase</Button>
```

Which is discouraged by the official documentation due to the possibility of multiple callback bindings in some scenarios.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Is there a way to pass along both the event object and an event args object to the event handler without using an arrow function?

Comment: Yeah you can call a function which would call another function with the argument. That would be even more messier

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal I saw a blog post with that pattern, looked messy.

Comment: Yes! Just do what you are doing now. The answer below is quite correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never it actively discouraged. The part of the documentation you are referring to is when you *aren't* passing extra arguments.

When you *are* passing arguments, the way you have presented is exactly the way to do it.

**Edit** The exception would be if the arguments are somehow constants (I can't think of a case when they would be, just flagging).

This pattern (the one you presented) is important especially for handlers within loops, where each item needs to call a callback/handler, but forward on an id or key or index.

Comment: Thanks, thought it was discouraged in general but if there isn't a better way to pass parameters I guess it is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to use `.bind` but it's not recommended because a new function is created upon each `render()` call.

```
updateProgress(arg, event) {
  console.log(arg, event); // Prints: 1 Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object ...
}

render() {
  return
    ...
    <Button onClick={this.updateProgress.bind(this, 1)}>Increase</Button>
}
```

Comment: Isn't this worse still? It binds on every button click, not just on every render? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It's correct, it binds on every render. Every button click calls the bound function which is updateProgress

Comment: This is basically the same thing; an arrow function creates a new function on each `render()` call too. The main advantage of the arrow function is that it arguably has cleaner syntax.